# How to write a sentence into a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a sentence like !=This is great

How do I write the sentence into a .CSV file with "!" in the first column and "This is great" in another column?

Comment: Do you only have one sentence (which result in csv with only one row/entry) or this should be multiple sentences?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to_csv method

code:

```
import pandas as pd

col1 = []
col2 = []
f = '!=This is great'

l1 = f.split('=')
col1.append(l1[0])
col2.append(l1[1])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = col1
df['col2'] = col2
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: while this works, this can be achieved in 3 lines using builtin functions. I think this is overkill

Answer (score 1):

split the text, and write it to an output file:

```
text  = open('in.txt').read() #if from input file
text = '!=This is great' #if not from input file

with open('out.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(text.split('=')))
```

output:

```
!,This is great
```

if you have multiple lines, you will have to loop through the input file and split each one

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could write using standard io with `open()` and manually write with comma delimiter for each line, but `python` has [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) standard library that will help you with this. You could specify the `dialect`

```
In [1]: import csv   

In [2]: sentence="!=This is great"   

In [3]: with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as f: 
   ...:     my_csvwriter = csv.writer(f) 
   ...:     my_csvwriter.writerow(sentence.split("="))
```

With multiple data, assuming it's in list, you could iterate through it when writing.

```
with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as f: 
     my_csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
     for sentence in sentences:
         my_csvwriter.writerow(sentence.split("="))
```

This library helps handling comma in a sentence, instead of handling it yourself. For instance you have:

```
sentence = "!=Hello, my name is.."
with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as f: 
     my_csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
     my_csvwriter.writerow(sentence.split("="))

# This will be written: !,"Hello, my name is.."
# With that quote, you could still open it in excel without confusing it
# and it knows that `Hello, my name is..` is in the same column
```

Comment: you mean '!=This is great'